# how to hide header conditionally base using reactjs

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

How to hide header component conditionally wise see in my codesandbox 
I do not want schedule tab to display header how this possible

Please guide thanks

https://codesandbox.io/s/vvoqvk78

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could wrap your app with withRouter and access the current location from the location prop. This enables you to render the header conditionally:

```
  const App = props => (
  <div>
    {props.location.pathname !== "/schedule" && <Header />}
    <Main />
  </div>
);

export default withRouter(App);
```

Here is a [codepen](https://codesandbox.io/s/a-simple-react-router-v4tutorial-p6rni).

Hope this helps. Happy coding.

Comment: Thank @Domino987, Can you please explain what React.Fragment does ?

Comment: Here are the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html): They are just an invisible wrapper around your components so that you don't have to wrap them in a div, if you have some components which live side-by-side.